# Passar uma sequência determinado número de vezes em Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

Tenho a seguinte sequência:

```
{1,4,12,28,45,22}
```

Eu preciso que uma variável por exemplo:

```
seguinte = input(num('Insira um número: '))
```

De acordo com o número informado, ele iria passar o último item para o começo, sendo informados 2 ficaria:

```
{45,22,1,4,12,28}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar na pergunta o que tentou fazer também, assim como o resultado que obteve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set não é ordenável.**

Na sua questão voce usa o tipo `set` para definir a sequencia, em python esse tipo é uma estrutura de dados que representa uma sequencia denotando um conjunto matemático, ou seja voce não pode impor ou manter qualquer ordem particular dos elementos. O conceito abstrato de um conjunto matemático não pressupõe ordem, por exemplo, se vc criar um tipo `set` a partir de uma lista, o python automaticamente altera a ordem dos elementos para atender às diretivas internas de implementação do `set` otimizadas para executar as operações propostas para esse tipo.

Veja esses exemplos:

```
set={'z','b','c'}
print(set)
{'c', 'b', 'z'}

set.add('a')
print(set)
{'c', 'b', 'z', 'a'}

set.add('e')
print(set)
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'z'}

# Obs. Novos testes com os mesmos valores podem gerar resultados diferentes
```

Voce poderia conseguir o que deseja com `list`, veja:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst.remove(5)
print(lst)
[1, 2, 3, 4]

lst.insert(0,5)
print(lst)
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Dica:**
Para descobrir a posição de um elemento em uma lista, faça: `lst.index('elemento')`